# Kong Ingress default string append in URL

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

In my project we have configured Kong Ingress as API gateway.
When we configured Ingress as follows

```
ingress:
  name: kong-ingress
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: "true"
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: mt-amp-api-gateway
            port:
              number: 8080
```

But the problem is for accessing the service that is running in the endpoint `/api/service/endpoint` the url from the frontend is like this `localhost:xxxx/api/api/service/endpoint`.
That I need to append 2 /api to access my actual resource.
Is there a configuration to change the I can actually access like `localhost:xxxx/api/service/endpoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to disable `stip-path` and enable `path` annotation?
https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.7.x/references/annotations/#konghqcompath ?

Thank you

Comment: the actual problem is we set stip-path=true after changing as false we achieved what we are looking for.